# Prospect matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

i am new in django and i am stuck with this form problem. I have no idea what the error means.

> Prospect matching query does not exist.

it says the error occurs here: **if form.is_valid():**

here's my files:

**forms.py**

```
class ProspectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    full_name = forms.CharField(
        label="Full Name",
        max_length=120,
        required=False,
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label="E-mail",
        max_length=120,
        required=False,
    )

    contact_number = forms.CharField(
        label="Contact Number",
        max_length=14,
        required=False,
    )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        try:
            Prospect.objects.get(email=email)
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email is taken')
        except VendicsUser.DoesNotExist:
            return email

    def clean_number(self):
        number = self.cleaned_data.get('number')
        validate_integer(number)
        try:
            Prospect.objects.get(contact_number=number)
            raise forms.ValidationError('This number is taken')
        except VendicsUser.DoesNotExist:
            if len(number) < 11:
                return number
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Number is too short')

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'contact_form'
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('full_name', css_class='form_fields'),
            Field('email', css_class='form_fields'),
            Field('contact_number', css_class='form_fields'),
            Hidden('sub_domain', ''),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'SUBMIT', css_class='form_button'),
            )
        )
        super(ProspectForm, self).__init__(*args)

    class Meta:
        model = Prospect
        exclude = ['user']
```

**views.py**

```
def landingpage(request, subdomain=None):
    form = ProspectForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        # for future changes
        form.save()
        return redirect('' + subdomain + '/')

    context = {
        'subdomain': subdomain,
        'form': form,
    }
    user = get_object_or_404(WebDetail, domain=subdomain)
    return render(request, "landingpage/landingpage.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're attempting to get an object that doesn't exist in the database. You didn't post the backtrace but I think this is the problem:

```
try:
    Prospect.objects.get(email=email)
    raise forms.ValidationError('This email is taken')
except VendicsUser.DoesNotExist:
    return email
```

The `get()` raises a `Prospect.DoesNotExist` exception, not `VendicsUser.DoesNotExist`. The raised exception goes right past your `except` block. Update all code to reflect the exception you're trying to catch and you're good to go.

Comment: i didnt see that. i forgot to update the exception too. thank you. it works now.